# Grabbing output from exec

Tags: c, terminal, exec, fork

I'm trying to write a C program that grabs command output and then i'll be passing that to another program.

I'm having an issue, I cant work out how to get the command output and store it.  Below is a sample of what I have

```
if(fork() == 0){
   execl("/bin/ls", "ls", "-1", (char *)0);
   /* do something with the output here */
}
else{
    //*other stuff goes here*
}
```

so basically im wondering if there is any way i can get the output from the "execl" and pass it to some thing else (e.g. via storing it in some kind of buffer).

Suggestions would be great.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

You have to create a pipe from the parent process to the child, using `pipe()`.
Then you must redirect `standard ouput` (STDOUT_FILENO) and `error output` (STDERR_FILENO) using `dup` or `dup2` to the pipe, and in the parent process, read from the pipe.
It should work.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define die(e) do { fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", e); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); } while (0);

int main() {
  int link[2];
  pid_t pid;
  char foo[4096];

  if (pipe(link)==-1)
    die("pipe");

  if ((pid = fork()) == -1)
    die("fork");

  if(pid == 0) {

    dup2 (link[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
    close(link[0]);
    close(link[1]);
    execl("/bin/ls", "ls", "-1", (char *)0);
    die("execl");

  } else {

    close(link[1]);
    int nbytes = read(link[0], foo, sizeof(foo));
    printf("Output: (%.*s)\n", nbytes, foo);
    wait(NULL);

  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks heaps! the great example that shows how to read from it won it for you.

Comment: I can read the man pages on dup2, execl, etc, which explains the function calls, but I don't understand the overall picture. Can somebody elaborate why we need to fork? Why do we close the links when we do, and why the wait(NULL) at the end?

Comment: Indeed fork might not be needed. But if you want to perform operations at the end of the chile task, you have to fork a new process. Wait ensures that parent's process don't quit bedore child.

Comment: I found this explanation in my copy of [APUE](http://www.apuebook.com/), section 1.6: "In the child, we call `exec` to execute the command [...]. This replaces the child process with the new program file. The combination of `fork` followed by `exec` is called spawning a new process on some operating systems. In the UNIX System, the two parts are separated into individual functions."

Comment: Okay, all starting to make sense now. From the man page: "The `exec()` family of functions replaces the current process image with a new process image."

Answer (score 34):

Open a pipe, and change stdout to match that pipe.

```
 #include <sys/types.h>
 #include <unistd.h>
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>

 int pipes[2];

 pipe(pipes); // Create the pipes

 dup2(pipes[1],1); // Set the pipe up to standard output
```

After that, anything which goes to stdout,(such as through printf), comes out pipe[0].

```
FILE *input = fdopen(pipes[0],"r");
```

Now you can read the output like a normal file descriptor. For more details, look at [this](http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/libc/Creating-a-Pipe.html)

Comment: Thanks great awnser, sorry you didnt get the win.

Comment: this is much clearer answer in my opinion, would deserve to be the top

Answer (score 7):

Thanks Jonathan Leffler, and i optimize the above code for it can't read all response for one time.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

#define die(e) do { fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", e); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); } while (0);

int main() {
  int link[2];
  pid_t pid;
  char foo[4096 + 1];
  memset(foo, 0, 4096);

  if (pipe(link)==-1)
    die("pipe");

   if ((pid = fork()) == -1)
    die("fork");

  if(pid == 0) {

    dup2 (link[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
    close(link[0]);
    close(link[1]);
    execl("/bin/ls", "ls", "-1", (char *)0);
    die("execl");
  } else {
    close(link[1]);
    int nbytes = 0;
    std::string totalStr;
    while(0 != (nbytes = read(link[0], foo, sizeof(foo)))) {
        totalStr = totalStr + foo;
        printf("Output: (%.*s)\n", nbytes, foo);
        memset(foo, 0, 4096);
    }
    wait(NULL);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the output in a string (char *), here's an option (for Linux at least):

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/uio.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

char* qx(char** cmd, int inc_stderr) {
  int stdout_fds[2];
  pipe(stdout_fds);

  int stderr_fds[2];
  if (!inc_stderr) {
    pipe(stderr_fds);
  }

  const pid_t pid = fork();
  if (!pid) {
    close(stdout_fds[0]);
    dup2(stdout_fds[1], 1);
    if (inc_stderr) {
      dup2(stdout_fds[1], 2);
    }

    close(stdout_fds[1]);

    if (!inc_stderr) {
      close(stderr_fds[0]);
      dup2(stderr_fds[1], 2);
      close(stderr_fds[1]);
    }

    execvp(*cmd, cmd);
    exit(0);
  }

  close(stdout_fds[1]);

  const int buf_size = 4096;
  char* out = malloc(buf_size);
  int out_size = buf_size;
  int i = 0;
  do {
    const ssize_t r = read(stdout_fds[0], &out[i], buf_size);
    if (r > 0) {
      i += r;
    }

    if (out_size - i <= 4096) {
      out_size *= 2;
      out = realloc(out, out_size);
    }
  } while (errno == EAGAIN || errno == EINTR);

  close(stdout_fds[0]);

  if (!inc_stderr) {
    close(stderr_fds[1]);
    do {
      const ssize_t r = read(stderr_fds[0], &out[i], buf_size);

      if (r > 0) {
        i += r;
      }

      if (out_size - i <= 4096) {
        out_size *= 2;
        out = realloc(out, out_size);
      }

    } while (errno == EAGAIN || errno == EINTR);

    close(stderr_fds[0]);
  }

  int r, status;
  do {
    r = waitpid(pid, &status, 0);
  } while (r == -1 && errno == EINTR);

  out[i] = 0;

  return out;
}

int main() {
  char* argv[3];
  argv[0] = "ls";
  argv[1] = "-la";
  argv[2] = NULL;
  char* out = qx(argv, 0);
  printf("%s", out);
  free(out);
}
```