# Capturing output from execv()

Tags: c, shell, exec

I am trying to call a shell function using fork() and exec() and I don't know how to get the output. Precisely, this is what my code does:

```
if (!fork()){
   execv(factor, arg);
}
```

How could I get the output of "factor" ?

Comment: [You'll need to open a pipe and then connect that to the child process's stdout.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7292642)

Comment: Also consider [`popen()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/popen)