# Get grep value using execl

Tags: c, linux, bash, shell, grep

I'm trying to make a program which invokes the `ls` and `grep` system calls using `exec`. Specifically I have to execute `ls > tmp; grep ­-c pattern < tmp` in order to count the number of files that fulfill the pattern. As you can see I save the content of ls in tmp file and then I want to use grep to count the files.

Let's supose `pattern = txt`. I'm trying things like the following code:

```
char *a = "ls > tmp";
char *b = " -c ";
char *fin = " < tmp";
char *comanda;
if((comanda = malloc(strlen(pattern)+strlen(pattern)+1)) != NULL){
  comanda[0] = '\0';   // ensures the memory is an empty string
  strcat(comanda,b);
  strcat(comanda, pattern);
  strcat(comanda,fin);
} else {
    return -1;
}

ret = execl("/bin/sh","sh","-c",a,NULL);
ret = execl("/bin/sh","sh","-c",comanda, NULL);
```

But it shows me the following error: `ls: cannot access  > tmp: No such file or directory`. So I don't know how to get the value of `grep`, because the `execl` function does not return the value, so how can I achieve the `grep` value?

Comment: You need to run `execl` in a child process created with `fork()`. `execl()` replaces the current process with the program you run, it only returns if it gets an error trying to load the program.

Comment: That's my actual point, in a child process i will use `execl`, but anyway I get the same error: `ls: cannot access  > tmp: No such file or directory`

Comment: I can't reproduce that error unless I change it to `char *a = "ls '> tmp'";`

Comment: Can you show me your code please?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/fQxxEv7t

Comment: Pattern value is `txt` but this is not the problem. So you actually can run it without error?

Comment: Yes, I run it without error. `pattern` doesn't really matter, because the second `execl` never runs.

Comment: Where is `grep` in the program? Shouldn't it be `char *b = "grep -c "`?

Comment: Yes, it should be, but I am actually trying to implement Eliot's code. Basically I'm trying to use `execl("/bin/sh", "sh", "-c", "ls > tmp; grep -c 'pattern' < tmp", (char *)NULL);` now because what I was trying is giving me error. Can we chat?

Comment: I see a problem. You have `strlen(pattern)+strlen(pattern)+1`. It should be `strlen(b)+strlen(pattern)+strlen(fin)+1`

Comment: I was modifying the code at this moment, so I already had it in mind, but thank you for your help too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the output of a command, you need to use a pipe.

Have a look at : [Connecting n commands with pipes in a shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8082932/connecting-n-commands-with-pipes-in-a-shell)

You could just do:

```
ls | grep -c pattern
```

If you just want to get files with a specific pattern in filename you might want to use `find`

```
find your_path/ -name "*pattern*" | wc -l
```

Have a look at [Grabbing output from exec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7292642/grabbing-output-from-exec) to get the output of execl

Here is an example, replace the 4th argument of execl with whatever you want :)

(`execl("/bin/sh", "sh", "-c", "ls > tmp; grep -c 'pattern' < tmp", (char *)NULL);`)

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
   int fd[2];
   pipe(fd);

   if (fork() == 0)
   {
      close(fd[0]);

      dup2(fd[1], 1);
      dup2(fd[1], 2);
      close(fd[1]);

      execl("/bin/sh", "sh", "-c", "find your_path -name '*pattern*' | wc -l", (char *)NULL);
   }
   else
   {
      char buffer[1024] = {0};

      close(fd[1]);

      while (read(fd[0], buffer, sizeof(buffer)) != 0)
      {
         write(1, buffer, strlen(buffer));
         memset (buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));
      }
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: The problem is that I have to use `ls > tmp; grep ­-c pattern < tmp` as a requeriment. So I will have a look to the pipes.

Comment: Well, if you don't have to use `execl`, use `system` which enables you to have redirections. Otherwise, play with `fork` and  `dup2`.

Comment: I can't use `system`, this is another requeriment too.

Comment: He's not passing `>` as an argument, he's calling `/bin/sh` and passing it a command line that contains the redirection. Why isn't the shell parsing the command?

Comment: Yep, you're write, I didn't remark the sh -c at first.

Comment: And when I try his code, I don't get the error. He must not have posted his actual code.

Comment: Okay, with your code I could find a solution, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You're not allocating the correct amount of space for `comanda`, because you don't add the sizes of all the variables correctly. So if the size is too small, you'll write outside the array bounds when you do all the `strcat`, and this will cause undefined behavior.

You don't need the temporary file, you can just pipe from `ls` to `grep`. I've also added quotes around the pattern in case it contains special characters.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    char *a = "ls | grep -c '";
    char *fin = "'";
    char *pattern = "foo";
    char *comanda;
    if((comanda = malloc(strlen(a) + strlen(pattern) + strlen(fin) +1)) != NULL){
        strcpy(comanda,a);
        strcat(comanda,pattern);
        strcat(comanda,fin);
    } else {
        return -1;
    }
    int ret = execl("/bin/sh","sh","-c", comanda, (char*)NULL);
    perror("execl"); // Can only get here if there's an error
}
```