# Can't trace a subprocess's syscalls which calls execve using ptrace and seccomp

Tags: c, linux

I am creating a [syscall tracer using seccomp](https://www.alfonsobeato.net/c/filter-and-modify-system-calls-with-seccomp-and-ptrace/). I don't change anything in the system call, I just log it in my structure and when the process finishes - I dump this structure on a disk.

When I run my program like this (it's called **tracer**):

> tracer env

Everything works well, and I see the logs in the file after.
However, if I try to trace a program which calls `execve` inside, it fails:

> tracer watch -n1 env

or

> tracer strace -o /tmp/log env

fails with the stdout

> env: error while loading shared libraries: cannot create cache for search path: Cannot allocate memory

and the log:

```
$ cat /tmp/log
execve("/usr/bin/env", ["env"], [/* 19 vars */]) = 0
brk(NULL)                               = 0x415000
mmap(0xffffffffffffffda, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x2
writev(103, [{iov_base="env", iov_len=3}, {iov_base=": ", iov_len=2}, {iov_base="error while loading shared libraries", iov_len=36}, {iov_base=": ", iov_len=2}, {iov_base="", iov_len=0}, {iov_base="", iov_len=0}, {iov_base="cannot create cache for search path", iov_len=35}, {iov_base=": ", iov_len=2}, {iov_base="Cannot allocate memory", iov_len=22}, {iov_base="\n", iov_len=1}], 10) = 127
+++ exited with 127 +++
```

Notice the weird `mmap` address and its return value. I don't understand what is wrong and why does this happen. Any other program works fine, so I guess the problem is with copying `seccomp` filters to the forked process which calls `execve`.

Here are my `seccomp` rules:

```
struct sock_filter filter[] = {
    BPF_STMT(BPF_LD + BPF_W + BPF_ABS, offsetof(struct seccomp_data, nr)),
    BPF_JUMP(BPF_JMP + BPF_JEQ + BPF_K, __NR_openat, 0, 1),
    BPF_STMT(BPF_RET + BPF_K, SECCOMP_RET_TRACE),
    BPF_JUMP(BPF_JMP + BPF_JEQ + BPF_K, __NR_write, 0, 1),
    BPF_STMT(BPF_RET + BPF_K, SECCOMP_RET_TRACE),
    BPF_JUMP(BPF_JMP + BPF_JEQ + BPF_K, __NR_mmap, 0, 1),
    BPF_STMT(BPF_RET + BPF_K, SECCOMP_RET_TRACE),
    BPF_JUMP(BPF_JMP + BPF_JEQ + BPF_K, __NR_mprotect, 0, 1),
    BPF_STMT(BPF_RET + BPF_K, SECCOMP_RET_TRACE),
    BPF_JUMP(BPF_JMP + BPF_JEQ + BPF_K, __NR_close, 0, 1),
    BPF_STMT(BPF_RET + BPF_K, SECCOMP_RET_TRACE),
    BPF_STMT(BPF_RET + BPF_K, SECCOMP_RET_ALLOW),
};
```

I don't list the whole code as it is obvious and can be only written in a single way, also, it is written in the article I referred to above. The problem is also known [in the Internet](https://www.bountysource.com/issues/38929844-segsegv-with-recent-kernel-and-seccomp) but I was not able to find any solution. If you still insist on the whole code (I doubt that) or MCVE, I can provide it.

Also, when I add the `execve` trace I have different behavior:

```
struct sock_filter filter[] = {
    BPF_STMT(BPF_LD + BPF_W + BPF_ABS, offsetof(struct seccomp_data, nr)),
    BPF_JUMP(BPF_JMP + BPF_JEQ + BPF_K, __NR_openat, 0, 1),
    BPF_STMT(BPF_RET + BPF_K, SECCOMP_RET_TRACE),
    BPF_JUMP(BPF_JMP + BPF_JEQ + BPF_K, __NR_write, 0, 1),
    BPF_STMT(BPF_RET + BPF_K, SECCOMP_RET_TRACE),
    BPF_JUMP(BPF_JMP + BPF_JEQ + BPF_K, __NR_mmap, 0, 1),
    BPF_STMT(BPF_RET + BPF_K, SECCOMP_RET_TRACE),
    BPF_JUMP(BPF_JMP + BPF_JEQ + BPF_K, __NR_mprotect, 0, 1),
    BPF_STMT(BPF_RET + BPF_K, SECCOMP_RET_TRACE),
    BPF_JUMP(BPF_JMP + BPF_JEQ + BPF_K, __NR_close, 0, 1),
    BPF_STMT(BPF_RET + BPF_K, SECCOMP_RET_TRACE),
    BPF_JUMP(BPF_JMP + BPF_JEQ + BPF_K, __NR_execve, 0, 1),
    BPF_STMT(BPF_RET + BPF_K, SECCOMP_RET_TRACE),
    BPF_STMT(BPF_RET + BPF_K, SECCOMP_RET_ALLOW),
};
```

The log becomes:

```
$ cat /tmp/log
execve(0xffffffffffffffda, ["env"], [/* 19 vars */]) = -1 ENOSYS (Function not implemented)
getpid()                                = 15535
exit_group(1)                           = ?
+++ exited with 1 +++
```

> Linux 4.4 aarch64, Linux 4.15 x86-64

The more time I spend on this problem, the more I realize that the problem is actually in the kernel's source code. [It copies the filters from one process to another](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/b4b52b881cf08e13d110eac811d4becc0775abbf/kernel/fork.c#L1575), child one but they don't copy the implementation, and so all of the `SECCOMP_RET_TRACE` rules are copied and there is no tracer in the child, so every system call in the subchild returns `-ENOSYS` as there is no tracer there, however, the rules are copied.

Comment: It may be the way _[message traffic from `execve` needs to be handled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7292642/grabbing-output-from-exec)_ that is causing the problem.

Comment: @ryyker Thank you for the help, but I am not sure how these two problems are connected? Could you clarify a bit, please?

Comment: They may not be. It was a shot in the dark.  Given it is very unlikely that your environment and conditions can be reproduced easily, what is left is trying to deduce causation from the the words used to describe the problem, eg:  _however_ ... _with execve, it fails_ part in the first part of your post.  I see you have edited in what appears to be a pseudo-conclusion on the nature of the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a way to solve this problem. To set up the tracer for children processes as well or at least to avoid the `ENOSYS` problem for sub-children, we can specify the `PTRACE_O_TRACEFORK` and `PTRACE_O_TRACECLONE` flag while setting **ptrace** options like that:

```
ptrace(PTRACE_SETOPTIONS, child, 0, PTRACE_O_TRACESECCOMP | PTRACE_O_TRACEFORK | PTRACE_O_TRACECLONE);
```

The reason why we need to add both is not easy to explain briefly. At first, it is architecture and **libc**-dependent which syscalls are present in the system and which are used by the programs (usually, through the **libc** implementation). Perhaps, even this list is not full: we may also have to track `VFORK` and other ways related to cloning (or spawning) a thread or a process (remember, thread are light-weight processes in Linux). So, what these options do is specified in the [`man`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ptrace.2.html):

> `PTRACE_O_TRACECLONE` (since Linux 2.5.46)
>   Stop the tracee at the next clone(2) and automatically
>   start tracing the newly cloned process, which will
>   start with a `SIGSTOP`, or `PTRACE_EVENT_STOP` if
>   `PTRACE_SEIZE` was used.  A waitpid(2) by the tracer will
>   return a status value such that
>
> ```
> status>>8 == (SIGTRAP | (PTRACE_EVENT_CLONE<<8))
> ```
>
> The PID of the new process can be retrieved with `PTRACE_GETEVENTMSG`. This option may not catch clone(2) calls in all cases. If the tracee calls clone(2) with the `CLONE_VFORK` flag, `PTRACE_EVENT_VFORK` will be delivered instead if `PTRACE_O_TRACEVFORK` is set; otherwise if the tracee calls clone(2) with the exit signal set to `SIGCHLD`, `PTRACE_EVENT_FORK` will be delivered if `PTRACE_O_TRACE‐FORK` is set.

The reason why it works in my case is that after simple cloning, `seccomp` rules were copied to the cloned process, but the tracer wasn't. By specifying these flags, the parent process becomes the tracer automatically for every child process, and so, as rules are copied, and tracer is specified, everything works like a charm.

**NOTE**
As using this way the parent process becomes the tracer, you will also need to wait for all children and sub-children, not only the process you actually spawned. To do this, use `-1` as a pid argument in `waitpid` or similar syscalls:

```
const pid_t childWaited = waitpid(-1, &status, 0);
// but not const pid_t result = waitpid(myChildPid, &status, 0);
```